# VisualForce: Parameter passed to controller as null

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

For some reason, the SelectedRow Id keeps coming up as null when trying to delete a row, can't figure out why. I have a table built into my page and I want to add a commandlink to delete a specific row. It keeps coming up as null when trying to delete it.

**My page:**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="main">
<table>
<tr>
 <apex:repeat value="{!headers}" var="h">
  <td class="hdr">{!h}</td>
 </apex:repeat>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!hours}" var="a">
 <tr>

 <td><apex:commandLink action="{!RowDelete}" value="delete" id="deleterow"/> 
 <apex:param assignto="{!SelectedRow}" value="{!a.id}" name="{!a.id}" />
 </td>


  <td ><apex:inputField value="{!a.Project__c}" /></td>
  <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Date__c}" /></td>
  <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.StartTime__c}" /></td>
  <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.EndTime__c}" /></td>
  <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Comments__c}" style="width:300px"/></td>

 </tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

**My Controller:**

```
// class variables

id  MonthlyReport;
public string SelectedRow {get;set{SelectedRow=value;system.debug('TESTING SelectedRow   Value is '+SelectedRow );}}
Reported_Hour__c[] hoursl; 


// To Delete Row
public pagereference RowDelete() {

 system.debug('TESTING: SelectedRow value is '+SelectedRow);
 Reported_Hour__c rh = [select id from Reported_Hour__c where id =: this.SelectedRow];
 delete rh;
 return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could dump the `name` bit from

```
<apex:param assignto="{!SelectedRow}" value="{!a.id}" name="{!a.id}" />
```

or maybe type there something irrelevant (`selectedRowParam` for example). VF is a bit quirky in that regard.

Check http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html for some inspiration?

Comment: Thanks. I tried all these options, as well as do what the link says but still was not able to resolve this.

Comment: Use the JS console in your favourite browser to check what's in the request parameters when you click your link. If it's being passed in URL for example - inspect the param name, maybe you'd be able to attack it via `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedRowparam');`?